# postgres plpgsql insert jsonb without escaping double quotes

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql, psycopg2

I am using `psycopg2` to interact with a postgres (v13) data base. I intend to dynamically create sql scripts to create tables, functions, etc. for execution in the db.

I created as script to do an upsert to a table with two `boolean` and one `jsonb` columns.  The script and a toy table are at this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1ccf49a3c3314bbe271fdb2bb746618d).  It works perfectly.

The problem is when I try to get the same results dynamically with `psycopg2`.  I created a 'toy' example.  The set up code below creates a simple 3 column table with 2 boolean and one jsonb column.  Connectivity is set up plus some sql scripts to create the upsert functions (as used in the fiddle above) and to call/test the function:

```
from psycopg2 import connect
from psycopg2.extras import Json
import pandas as pd


conn_graphstruct = connect(host='localhost', database='graphstruct_data',
                                            port='5665', user='postgres', password='postgres')

cursor_graphstruct = conn_graphstruct.cursor()

def graph_script(x):
    cursor = cursor_graphstruct
    conn = conn_graphstruct
    try:
        cursor.execute(x)
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        conn.rollback()

def graph_query(x):
    temp = pd.read_sql(x, conn_graphstruct)
    if not temp.empty:
        return temp
    
def graph_fetch(x):
    cursor = cursor_graphstruct
    conn = conn_graphstruct
    try:
        cursor.execute(x)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        return records
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

make_table = '''
    drop table if exists graphy;
    create temporary table graphy (
          directed boolean, 
          multigraph boolean,
          graph jsonb);
    create unique index unique_db_name on graphy ((graph->>'name'));

    insert into graphy(directed, multigraph, graph) values(FALSE,FALSE, '{"node_default": {},
    "edge_default": {}, "name": "test_8"}');
'''

make_procedure = '''
    drop procedure if exists p_upsert_meta();
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  p_upsert_meta(x bool, y bool, z jsonb) LANGUAGE plpgsql
    as $$
    begin
        INSERT into graphy (directed, multigraph, graph) values (x,y,z)
        ON CONFLICT ((graph->>'name'))
        DO update
        set (directed, multigraph, graph) = (x,y,z);
    END 
    $$;
'''

run_procedure = '''
    call p_upsert_meta(FALSE,TRUE, '{"node_default": {}, "edge_default": {},
    "name": "test_10"}');
    call p_upsert_meta(FALSE,TRUE, '{"node_default": {}, "edge_default": {},
    "name": "test_10"}');    
'''
```

I then run the scripts.  First using the scripts as defined and then using a dynamic sql approach where I compose the query.

```
graph_script(make_table)
graph_script(make_procedure)
graph_script(run_procedure)

directed = False
multi = False
graph_name = 'proto_1'

graph = '{"node_default": Null, "edge_default": True,"name": "' + graph_name + '"}'
print(graph)
graph_script('call p_upsert_meta({},{},{})'.format(directed, multi, Json(graph)))
graph_script('call p_upsert_meta({},{},{})'.format(directed, multi, Json(graph)))
```

What *should* result are three entries in the table.  Instead a query on the jsonb column (`graph`):

```
query = '''
        select graph
        from graphy
    '''

graph_fetch(query)
```

Results in:

```
{"node_default": Null, "edge_default": True,"name": "proto_1"}  -- composed string

[({'name': 'test_8', 'edge_default': {}, 'node_default': {}},),
 ({'name': 'test_10', 'edge_default': {}, 'node_default': {}},),
 ('{"node_default": Null, "edge_default": True,"name": "proto_1"}',), -- text not jsonb
 ('{"node_default": Null, "edge_default": True,"name": "proto_1"}',)] -- text not jsonb
```

If I don't use psycopg2.extras.Json I get this error - `syntax error at or near "{" LINE 1: call p_upsert_meta(False,False,{"node_default": Null, "edge_...`.  But using `Json` escapes all the double quotes.  When that happens `CONFLICT` won't work.  I've tried casting `z` and `graph` within the function and using `import json` methods.

What am I missing to properly insert a jsonb without the escaped double quotes?

Notes:

1. yes, I have to use psycopg2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are passing a string to `Json`. `Json` does adaptation of Python types to Json(b) in Postgres. A quick example:

```
cur.execute('insert into json_test (fld_jsonb) values(%s)', [Json({"node_default": None, "edge_default": True,"name": "graph_name"})])

cur.execute('insert into json_test (fld_jsonb) values(%s)', [Json('{"node_default": None, "edge_default": True,"name": "graph_name"}')]) 

con.commit()

cur.execute("select fld_jsonb from json_test")                                                                                                                            

rs = cur.fetchall()                          

# Python dict as Json value
rs[0][0]                                                                                                                                                                  
{'name': 'graph_name', 'edge_default': True, 'node_default': None}

# Python string as Json value
rs[1][0]                                                                                                                                                                  
'{"node_default": None, "edge_default": True,"name": "graph_name"}'
```

If you want the `Json` adaptation to work properly then use appropriate Python types: `list` for `json array` and `dict` for `json object`. This also applies to the contained types so `None` instead of `Null` on the Python side.

**UPDATE**

If you want to use a string then don't use the `Json` adaptation:

```
cur.execute('insert into json_test (fld_jsonb) values(%s)', ['{"node_default": null, "edge_default": true,"name": "graph_name"}'])
con.commit()

rs[2][0]                                                                                                                                                                  
{'name': 'graph_name', 'edge_default': True, 'node_default': None}
```

Though then you will need to use JSON values e.g. `null` and `true` instead of `None` and `True`.

Comment: Tnx!  The part about how Json works was key.  I'd seen many examples and even the docs but somehow that nuance didn't register at all.